# Wraparound in the React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

```
const data1 = [
   { name: 'one' },
   { name: 'two' },
   { name: 'three' },
   { name: 'four' },
   { name: 'five'},
   { name: 'six'}
  ];


const colors = ['red', 'purple', 'violet', 'blue'];
```

I want output in this format---

```
  render(){...
      <Button color="from array colors">//Values from data1 here</Button>
```

These are the two arrays I have.Now my question is how do I access the colors in wraparound fashion i.e., 'five' of data1 should be colored with colors[0].Pls help coz I am a React newbie.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: it is hard to tell what you want. please learn how to ask more clear questions.

Comment: maybe u should assign an id to the button, then set the color of it like this `document.getElementById("your-id").background-color = colors[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *wraparound*, you mean to choose color[0], on the 5th element since there are only 4 colors,  You can use `modulo` `%`

Like:

```js
const data1 = [
 { name: 'one' },
 { name: 'two' },
 { name: 'three' },
 { name: 'four' },
 { name: 'five'},
 { name: 'six'}
];

const colors = ['red', 'purple', 'violet', 'blue'];

data1.forEach((v, i) => {
  let color = colors[i % colors.length];
  
  //Construct HTML and console for testing
  console.log('<Button color="' + color + '">' + v.name + '</Button>');
});
```